# showerhead for showers with little water?

Tags: bathroom, water

My shower delivers a very-low 1.4GPM. I checked by removing the current shower-head, and filling 1-gallon bottles for a minute.

What shower-head will help me with such low water pressure?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.5 GPM is a common rating for showerheads and they go lower..  Maybe your faucet is built for such a showerhead, and it was originally mismatched to the wrong head.

Comment: So, its 1.4gpm with the shower head off? Maybe someone can answer if the gpm is normal with the shower head removed.

Comment: There may be mixing valves for showers that have flow restrictors in them. I can imagine certain localities where the local code specifies such a valve due to chronic water shortage.  Or someone, for their own reasons, installed a flow limiting mixing valve to limit the flow of this particular shower. If the shower is giving only 1.4 gal/min *with the head removed*, then how much is being delivered with the head in place? Removal of the flow restrictor in the shower head would give the maximum the valve would allow. Removal of the flow restrictor should be straightforward and easy.

Comment: Have you checked the flow rate at other use points in the house? What about outside faucets? If the flow rate at other points is also low, then maybe the cut-off valve to the house (maybe the city cut-off at the meter) is only half open. If other points have larger flow, then maybe you have a flow limiting mixing valve or a malfunctioning valve. If 1.4 gal/min is all you can get out this valve, then you could get the best performance by getting a low flow head and removing the flow restrictor in the head. A low flow head is designed to work at low flow.

Comment: What kind of mixing valve do you have--single handle or two handle? Some single handle valves have stop valves to shut off flow to change the cartridge. If one or both of these stop valves were not fully open, then this would produce low flow.

Comment: It's 1.4GPM without the showerhead. I live in an apartment. Is it possible to get a decent shower when the pressure (without showerhead) is 1.4 GPM?

Answer (score 1):

There is a flow restrictor in all shower heads. The usual design is a plastic disc with two or three holes in it.

The maximum flow allowed by law in a new head as offered for sale is 2.5 gal/min. Most people find this adequate, generous but welcome, or even too much. Lower flow shower heads have a more restrictive restrictor (smaller or fewer holes in the restrictor disc) to give a lower flow. Since most people limit their shower by time rather than amount of water, this saves hot water. So the 1.4 gal/min that you have is probably by design of the restrictor and is not a sign of low water pressure.

It is not illegal for a consumer to remove the restrictor and get greater flow. You can probably find a youtube video on how to do this.

**EDIT**

I got new low flow shower heads (1.5 gal/min, hand holdable with hose) for our house and our old tankless water heater began working erratically. For a long time I didn't realize it was due to changing to the low flow heads. The water heater would shut off in the middle of a shower because the flow rate was insufficient to keep it on. (Tankless heaters have a minimum flow for the unit to turn on and to stay on.)

Once I realized what the problem was I tried to drill out the holes in the restrictors, but this still didn't solve the problem. Once I removed the restrictors entirely the heater would stay on. (A tank water heater does not have this problem. It will deliver a trickle of hot water if that's what you want, or if there is a small leak).

Before I tried drilling out the flow restrictor I emailed a local expert plumbing supply asking about calibrated 2.0 gal/min restrictors -- they replied they had just exactly that. But when I got there it turned out that the ones they had were too large to fit in the cheap ($15) heads I had. I then tried drilling out the existing restrictors, but when my first attempt didn't work I just removed them entirely. I wash our dog in one of these showers and the extra flow is welcome for that use. A flow of 1.5 gal/min is too low to efficiently wash a dog with a thick or long coat.

These are handheld heads with hose to them and I have since installed the same model in two other houses where they are apparently working fine with the original 1.5 gal/min flow restrictors in place. One of these houses has a tank (40 or 50 gal) and the lower flow will reduce the number of incidences where one showering uses all the hot water. The other house has the same model of tankless heater we have, but that heater seems to be accepting the a 1.5 gal/min head.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Without the showerhead, water pours at 1.4 GPM. I was thinking this amount of pressure was too low.

Comment: Is 1.4 GPM (without a showerhead) good-enough pressure for a decent shower?

Comment: It would be a matter of personal preference whether you can accept 1.4 gpm or not, but if all you have is 1.4 gpm without the shower head in place, then a low flow shower head **with the flow restrictor removed** will make the best use of that flow rate. If you would put on a low flow shower head and leave the flow restrictor in place, then you will get much less than 1.4 gpm, and it does not sound like you would be satisfied with that. You may be able to remove the flow restrictor in the head you have right now and used it without going to the trouble and expense of getting a new shower head.